# Create table is not having the expected number of rows

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

We are dealing with log data of machines which are in presto . A view is created in Teradata Query Grid which would query the presto and have the result set in databricks. For some other internal use case we are trying to create a table in Teradata but facing difficulty in doing so.

When we try to create a table in Teradata for a particular date which has 2610117,459,037,913088 records only 14K odd records get inserted to the target table. Below is the query for the same. xyz.view is the view created in TD query grid which eventually fetches the data from presto.

```
CREATE TABLE abc.test_table AS
    ( SELECT * FROM xyz.view WHERE event_date = '2020-01-29' )
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (MATERIAL_ID, SERIAL_ID);
```

But when we create the table with sample data (say sample 10000000), exact number of records we get in the table created like below:

```
    CREATE TABLE abc.test_table AS
    ( SELECT * FROM xyz.view WHERE event_date = '2020-01-29' sample 10000000)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (MATERIAL_ID, SERIAL_ID);
```

But again creating with a sample of 1 billion records gets us only 208 million odd records in our target table.
Can anyone please help in here as to why is this happening and if it is possible to create the table with 2610117,459,037,913088 records.

We are using TD 16 .

Comment: `2610117,459,037,913088`? Are you stating you have a table with 2.6e18 records in it for a single date? I only ask because your comma separators don't seem consistent and that would be about 30 trillion records per second.

Comment: Yes , I just had it pasted from the count(*) answer set of TD

Comment: And you don't find it strange that it's that high, or that it appears to be weirdly formatted? Even with a pitifully small ten bytes per record, that's going to consume 272 TB per second. That's seems like an awful lot of data, don't you think? I mean, I've worked on large systems that store hundreds of millions of rows but not thirty thousand times that much every single *second.* You might also want to consider that the currently fastest SSD drives have a write speed of about 4.4G/s, about 1/61,000th of what you need here. I'd suggest going back and checking those figures.

Comment: Is your target table `abc.test_table` a `SET` table or `MULTISET`?  If it's a `SET` table this will eliminate any duplicate rows that are attempted to be inserted.  You can find this out by doing a `SHOW TABLE abc.test_table` and it will say in the first line or two. Regarding your `sample 10000000`, if your source view / table doesn't have this many rows, it will only return as many as it has.  If you indeed want to get 10000000 rows, you should use `sample 10000000 with replacement`.

Comment: @paxdiablo : Thank you !!! . There seemed to be some issue with the format of TD studio . We executed the same in SQL assistant and got the right result.